# search contents of one file with contents of a second file using python

Tags: python

I have the following code which compares the items on the first column of input file1 with the contents of input file 2:

import os

```
newfile2=[]
outfile=open("outFile.txt","w")
infile1=open("infile1.txt", "r")
infile2=open("infile2.txt","r")
for file1 in infile1:
    #print file1
    file1=str(file1).strip().split("\t")
    print file1[0]
    for file2 in infile2:
        if file2 == file1[0]:
            outfile.write(file2.replace(file2,file1[1]))
        else:
            outfile.write(file2)
```

input file 1:

```
Modex_xxR_SL1344_3920   Modex_sseE_SL1344_3920
Modex_seA_hemN  Modex_polA_SGR222_3950
Modex_GF2333_3962_SL1344_3966   Modex_ertd_wedS
```

input file 2:

```
Sardes_xxR_SL1344_4567  
Modex_seA_hemN
MOdex_uui_gytI
```

Since the input file 1 item (column 1, row 2) matches an item in input file 2 (row 2), then the column 2 item in input file 1 replaces the input file 2 item in the output file as follows (required output):

```
Sardes_xxR_SL1344_4567  
Modex_polA_SGR222_3950
MOdex_uui_gytI
```

So far my code is only outputting the items in input file 1. Can someone help modify this code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a `tsv` file, so let's go ahead and treat it as such. We'll build a tsv reader `csv.reader(fileobj, delimiter="\t")` that will iterate through `infile1` and build a translation dict from it. The dictionary will have keys of the first column and values of the second column per row.

Then using `dict.get` we can translate the line from `infile2` if it exists in our translation dict, or just write the line itself if there's no translation available.

```
import csv

with open("infile1.txt", 'r') as infile1,\
     open('infile2.txt', 'r') as infile2,\
     open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    trans_dict = dict(csv.reader(infile1, delimiter="\t"))

    for line in infile2:
        outfile.write(trans_dict.get(line.strip(),line.strip()) + "\n")
```

Result:

```
# contents of outfile.txt
Sardes_xxR_SL1344_4567
Modex_polA_SGR222_3950
MOdex_uui_gytI
```

**EDIT** as per your comment:

```
import csv

    with open("infile1.txt", 'r') as infile1:
        # build our translation dict
        trans_dict = dict(csv.reader(infile1, delimiter="\t"))

    with open("infile2.txt", 'r') as infile2,\
         open("outfile.txt", 'w') as outfile:
        # open the file to translate and our output file
        reader = csv.reader(infile2, delimiter="\t")
        # treat our file to translate like a tsv file instead of flat text
        for line in reader:
            outfile.write("\t".join([trans_dict.get(col, col) for col in line] + "\n"))
            # map each column from trans_dict, writing the whole row
            # back re-tab-delimited with a trailing newline
```

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks @Adam Smith. It worked perfectly. Just a few questions: In case infile2 contains multi-columns, instead of one column, is there a way to translate several lines? Would I need something like "for line[0]", "for line[1]", "for line[2]" etc in the loop? Or dict.get(line.strip[0](), line.strip[1]() etc)?

Comment: @RobJohn edited per your comment. There's a way to use `csv.writer` to make that `outfile.write` line less ugly, but I don't have time to remember how to do it atm

Comment: @RobJohn I THINK it's just `writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter="\t")` then `for line in reader: outfile.writerow([transdict.get(col, col) for col in line])`

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks once again @Adam Smith. The new version worked as well. Just one bracket missing in the last line of the code: outfile.write("\t".join([trans_dict.get(col, col) for col in line]) + "\n"). Kindly edit; hopefully someone else will find the codes useful. I really appreciate your time and help.